# Нужна отправка сообщения ботом. Значения из словаря в одно сообщение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Ситуация следующая: есть бот, проводящий некий опрос пользователя. По завершению опроса отправляет готовый результат админу чата. На данный момент код выглядит следующим образом:

```
await bot.send_message(id, f'Госпожа, у тебя новая запись:\n{' '.join(c for c in data.values())}')
await. state.finish()
```

Сейчас всё это выглядит следующим образом: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы каждое новое значение выводилось с новой строки. Всё что пока пришло в голову, это прогнать через for, без генератора. Но в таком случае каждое значение будет приходить отдельным сообщением.

Что я упустил? Есть идеи по поводу реализации данной идеи?

Нужен вот такой результат [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приходит отдельным сообщением, потому что генератор в реализован методе
Как вариант создать все это в отдельном списке и отправить уже список в сообщение '\n'.join(your_lst)

Comment: Извиняюсь, возможно плохо объяснил что именно хочу получить. Добавил фото желаемого результата в вопрос.

Comment: @СергейСолдатов в программирование зашёл месяц назад поэтому могу тупить)). Если я правильно понял, то предложенный вариант будет выглядеть таким образом: x= ' '.join(c for c in data.values()}  и отправлять я буду уже: await bot.send_message(id, f'какой-то текс\n{'\n'.join(x)}'). Так?

Comment: x = [c for c in data.values()]

await bot.send_message(id, f'какой-то текст:\n{'\n'.join(x)}')

Comment: Используйте разные кавычки для самой строки и для разделителя. А еще лучше - не добавляйте сложный код в f-строку - подготавливайте значение заранее или используйте метод format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря [методу `str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) происходит последовательная конкатенация строк: значения `str` и элементов итерируемого объекта.

В вашем случае последовательно объединяются `' '` и элементы `data.values()`.

Для желаемого результата добавьте в объект `str` сепаратор `'\n'`. Во избежание ошибок, связанных с ограничением f-строк, сепаратор можно реализовать следующим образом:

```
separator = '\n'

print(
    f"Here is the text:\n{separator.join(i for i in iterated_object)}"
)
```

Comment: Премного благодарен). Вчера главное попробовал и не вышло. Единственное что, пробовал сепаратор  '\n' без переменной, а сразу в строке.

Comment: Если вам помог ответ, отметьте его пожалуйста как верный =)